# Why doesn't this work? ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle11g

Why doesn't this work

```sql
SELECT FIRST_NAME,
       MIDDLE_NAME,
       LAST_NAME,
       EMP_MOBILE_NO,
       NEW_EMPNO ,
       SECTION_NAME,
       EMP_TYPE,
       JOINING_DATE
FROM EMP_OFFICIAL,EMP_PERSONAL 
where EMP_PERSONAL.STATUS='Active'
  and EMP_OFFICIAL.WORK_ENT='Worker'
  AND  EMP_OFFICIAL.EMPNO=EMP_PERSONAL.EMPNO
GROUP BY EMP_OFFICIAL.SECTION_NAMEORDER BY EMP_PERSONAL.NEW_EMPNO DESC
```

When I am  Query this show group By the expression

I will tried but no solution found

Comment: Don't tag spam... This is clearly a Oracle error, so don't tag random other RDBMS that have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Help us help you - share the table structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: Is this a typographical error, due to your lack of white space/line break between `SECTION_NAME` and `ORDER` in the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: Though, a `GROUP BY` with no aggregation make no sense either...

Comment: What is ```GROUP BY``` supposed to do in this query ? It is used for aggregate expressions (SUM/AVG/MIN...) but there is no such expression in your ```SELECT``` clause. Remove "GROUP BY EMP_OFFICIAL.SECTION_NAME"

Comment: 'SECTION_NAME' column have some empty data .

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; and your expected output. Your query does not make sense as you are not aggregating the data so `GROUP BY` appears irrelevant; it would help if you showed what you expect as input and output so we can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Looks like you simply want `ORDER BY`, instead of `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

lFirst does not have any aggregate function (MAX, MIN, SUM, COUNT...) so there is no need to have a GROUP BY clause. Do not confuse between DISTINCT row operator and GROUP BY clause.

Second, "BY EMP_PERSONAL.NEW_EMPNO DESC" Does not mean anything ! Is it a compement to GROUP BY or a part of ORDER BY ?

To solve the first part, rewrite your query as :

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME,LAST_NAME , EMP_MOBILE_NO,NEW_EMPNO , SECTION_NAME, EMP_TYPE, JOINING_DATE 
FROM   EMP_OFFICIAL,EMP_PERSONAL  
WHERE  EMP_PERSONAL.STATUS='Active' 
  AND  EMP_OFFICIAL.WORK_ENT='Worker'
  AND  EMP_OFFICIAL.EMPNO=EMP_PERSONAL.EMPNO
```

Also a JOIN must be write with the JOIN operator not as a cartesian product followed by a restriction. So rewrite your query as :

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME,LAST_NAME , EMP_MOBILE_NO,NEW_EMPNO , SECTION_NAME, EMP_TYPE, JOINING_DATE 
FROM   EMP_OFFICIAL
       JOIN EMP_PERSONAL  
          ON EMP_OFFICIAL.EMPNO=EMP_PERSONAL.EMPNO 
WHERE  EMP_PERSONAL.STATUS='Active' 
  AND  EMP_OFFICIAL.WORK_ENT='Worker'
```

This will be most optimized by the optimizer because it not spread time and operations to do the translation between false JOIN and real joins...

Comment: Saying that "a JOIN must be write with the JOIN operator" is incorrect. A comma join is the legacy Oracle syntax and is perfectly valid (if outdated).

Comment: valid does not mean quicker ! And the ISO standard joins are perfectly accepted by Oracle since a lot...

Comment: It makes no difference to the optimiser whether you write standard ANSI joins or obsolete comma joins. ANSI joins are more readable and make it harder to miss a join condition, that's all.

Comment: It is not as simple as you say... In fact Oracle optimizer like every other optimizer has a limit of time or number of instructions to find the best execution plan. When this limit is reached, the last less expensive plan is given, but that is not always the best. By forcing some conversion in using stupid pseudo joins in the bad Oracle old style, you give less chances to have a most powerfull plan...

Comment: It is not as simple as you say. The Oracle parser generally rewrites ANSI joins internal to comma joins/